# What's the word (or phrase) for the phenomenon that something suddenly works when you try to show an error

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

As the title describes, I'm looking for a word or phrase that describes the phenomenon that a bug/error/etc. disappears when you want to show it to someone.

Example:
Your Internet connection does not work properly. You try everything to fix it, but it won't work.
You call an expert but then when you want to show the issue to them, your Internet connection seems to be fine. Obviously, once your expert left, your Internet connection is broken again. Bad luck.

So, what would you call it?

Comment: It's 'embarassing'.

Comment: This is definitely not a duplicate. For posterity, I would say something like "it made a liar out of me."